# Bash variables to Python while executing bash script

Tags: python, bash

I read the related Questions before asking my question but it's kind of problem specific. I am executing a bash script and the result is stored in a .txt file. Immediately after the file is created, I need to use a number which is contained in the file to do some operations in Python. I take the variable of interest using grep as follows.

```
MeasureImageSimilarity.sh 3 2 myfile1 myfile2 results.txt
var=$(grep -Ewo "[+-]?[0-9]" result.txt)
```

My question now is how can i create an array of these "var" variables in Python if i put the above script in a loop. I am asking because i also need the indexes of the hypothetical for-loop that i want to iterate in.

Comment: Please add a sample text file which you're working with

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays ?

Comment: just run the grep using subprocess or use re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
a=subprocess.check_output('(grep -Ewo "[+-]?[0-9]" result.txt)', shell=True)
```

Since this will return a string you can perform:

```
a=float(a)
```

Hope it helps!